# How to lock down access between tenant users in a multi tenant laravel application

Tags: php, laravel

I am in the processed of building a multi tenant Laravel application where every tenant has their own database (which includes a users table).

The tenant is identified by the subdomain in the TenantServiceProvider and the the connection is changed to use the appropriate database when it figures out the tenant ID.

Everything is working as expected however I have come across a major security issue.

I log in to tenant1.mysite.com as user "John Doe" with ID 1

I change the url to tenant2.mysite.com and I am now logged in as "Jane Doe" who has an ID of 1 on the tenant2 site.

How can I prevent John Doe's session from being used on another tenant's site?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it; in your `Authenticate` middleware put a block such as;

When user logged-in successfully put the value `tenant1` in the user's session in a specified key.

`Session::put('domain', 'tenant1');`

in the same middleware even the authentication is correct, check whether the user's session match with the subdomain name. if they are matched then you proceed the user, else redirect him to login page.

`Session::get('domain') === $this->getSubDomain($request)`

```
public function getSubDomain(Request $request): string
{
    $urlSegments = explode('.', parse_url($request->url(), PHP_URL_HOST));

    return $urlSegments[0]; // this will return "tenant1"
}
```

Don't forget to remove `domain` from session after user logged-out.